# How to search in the math scope of a tex file only using texniccenter?

Tags: texniccenter

Say I want to look for occurances of a variable Y in a .tex file in texniccenter. Then it would make sense to restrict the search to occurances of Y that occur in a math environment. Thus the Y in

```
\begin{align}
Y=X^2
\end{align}
```

should be found, but the Y in

```
Ay, ay, sir!
```

should not. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write

```
\mathcode`Y = "8000 % cap Y
\mathcode`y = "8000 % small y
```

and you get an error in the line containing math Y (y).

Comment: Aah, this is a way to make LaTeX give you the locations of the variables. Not exactly what I asked, but useful anyway